# R throwing errors when trying to compile

Tags: r, compiler-errors, terminal

I am trying to use R to generate 2 files the first one actually generates pretty good but the 2nd one tells me the following:

> conteo_correlaciones.c:3:15: error: R.h: No such file or directory
>   conteo_correlaciones.c:4:24: error: Rinternals.h: No such file or
>   directory conteo_correlaciones.c:31: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’,
>   ‘asm’ or ‘**attribute**’ before ‘countcorrelations’

both R.h and Rinternals.h were copied from the R directory and they're in the same directory that the rest of the files but I can't get past this error, these files are being called by an include like this:

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
```

and what I'm doing in the terminal is:

```
R CMD SHLIB conteo_correlaciones.c
```

Which works great and generates me the correct file and:

```
gcc -dynamiclib conteo_correlaciones.c -o conteo_correlaciones.so
```

Which throws me the aforementioned error. Any idea what could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
```

to

```
#include "R.h"
#include "Rinternals.h"
```

if the header files are in the same directory like your code files.
Or you could add the correct include-path to gcc commandline (e.g. `-I/usr/share/R/include`).

Answer (score 8):

`R CMD SHLIB` adds all appropriate flags to compile your code. You cannot (reliably) compile your code "by hand". `R CMD SHLIB` already creates all necessary files, so you don't need to run `gcc` yourself.

For example, this is what `R CMD SHLIB` runs:

```
$ R CMD SHLIB foo.c
gcc -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include 
  -I/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Resources/include/x86_64 
  -I/usr/local/include    -fPIC  -g -O2 -c foo.c -o foo.o
gcc -arch x86_64 -std=gnu99 -dynamiclib -Wl,-headerpad_max_install_names
  -undefined dynamic_lookup -single_module -multiply_defined suppress
  -L/usr/local/lib -o foo.so foo.o -F/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/..
  -framework R -Wl,-framework -Wl,CoreFoundation
```

As you can see there is a long list of flags that are needed to create the proper binary. The first line is the compilation, the second one is linking. As you can see it's not even close to what you were trying to do "by hand".

As for the exact error - it's just one of many that you would get - in the above case you need to include R's include path with `-I`. There are others as well, so you don't want to go there, just stick with `R CMD SHLIB`.

Answer (score 0):

First locate where R.h is stored (it could be in /usr/include or /usr/local/include or anywhere if R has been installed from sources). In my case it is in /home/user/R/include/:

Then export the paths:

```
export CPATH=/home/user/R/include/
export C_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/user/R/include/
export CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/home/user/R/include/
export GCC_INCLUDE_DIR=/home/user/R/include/
```

The compilation should then run fine.