# Can the R package readODS be improved, as it gives errors on Linux during installation

Tags: r, linux, installation, package, ods

In the process of getting acquainted with R, I found another topic from 7 years ago with the suggestion to use the readODS package. However, when I tried to install readODS using R-Studio 1.3.1093 with R 4.0.3 on Fedora Linux 32, the install failed with a list of errors. I've omitted the output of the start of the installation. And FYI: gnumeric is installed.

```
<start of output omitted....>
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) : 
  namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.9 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package ‘lifecycle’
* removing ‘/home/huub/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/lifecycle’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘lifecycle’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘ellipsis’ is not available for package ‘vctrs’
* removing ‘/home/huub/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/vctrs’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘vctrs’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘ellipsis’, ‘fansi’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘utf8’, ‘vctrs’ are not available for package ‘pillar’
* removing ‘/home/huub/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/pillar’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘ellipsis’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘vctrs’ are not available for package ‘hms’
* removing ‘/home/huub/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/hms’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘hms’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘ellipsis’, ‘fansi’, ‘lifecycle’, ‘pillar’, ‘vctrs’ are not available for package ‘tibble’
* removing ‘/home/huub/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/tibble’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tibble’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘tibble’ is not available for package ‘cellranger’
* removing ‘/home/huub/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/cellranger’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘cellranger’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘hms’, ‘tibble’, ‘lifecycle’ are not available for package ‘readr’
* removing ‘/home/huub/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/readr’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘readr’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependencies ‘xml2’, ‘cellranger’, ‘readr’ are not available for package ‘readODS’
* removing ‘/home/huub/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/readODS’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘readODS’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/tmp/RtmpaKyR2b/downloaded_packages’
```

So I'd say, there's something to fix for this readODS package. Which is too bad, since I use LibreOffice (.ods) on a daily basis.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Fedora 32 (Thirty Two)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib64/libopenblas-r0.3.12.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.3 tools_4.0.3
```

Comment: Anything after the first error (*"namespace ‘rlang’ 0.4.9 is being loaded, but >= 0.4.10 is required"*) can be safely ignored until you solve that error and try again. Have you tried to install just that package manually, using `install.packages("rlang")`? Once that succeeds, try what you tried again. (You may need to repeat that for other packages if they also subsequently complain about a newer version being required.)

Comment: @r2evans Thanks for your reply. This is what installing rlang gives: capture.c:1:10: fatal error: Rinternals.h: No such file or directory
    1 | #include <Rinternals.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [/usr/lib64/R/etc/Makeconf:172: capture.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’

Comment: Yeah, that's a bad one. On most unix-like OSes, `Rinternals.h` is installed by default with R (e.g., in `r-base-core` on debian and ubuntu). Not finding that means either your installation is corrupted, or it is installed in a nonstandard location. I don't know if it'll help, but look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/33574039/3358272 if you know where your R is installed (and it is nonstandard). Please add the output from `sessionInfo()` or `devtools::session_info()` to your question.

Comment: Another thought, though, is to try to install the binary version of the packages. RStudio has a package repo that contains binaries for most unix-like OSes, I suggest you go to https://packagemanager.rstudio.com/ to learn how to use their repo for binary installs on your system. That should get you past the hurdle of installing `rlang` (and most things that need compiling), though I wonder/fear what else is different about your system.

Comment: R and R-Studio are installed via the dnf packagemanager. Output from sessionInfo() added to the queston. On the other note (stackoverflow link): no result on finding R.h

Comment: I can't help much with the redhat install, who knows what they did. The closest I've found so far is https://stackoverflow.com/q/63302815/3358272

Comment: Oh my, that doesn't look promising for future efforts.

Comment: Try the binary-package install I suggested. Really, it can work well.

Comment: Ok, that is a very different story indeed. I removed the RStudio installation, and installed just R according to that binary-package via dnf. Then rlang, which installed just fine. So, somehow RStudio is messed up.

Comment: Unfortunately, the next step to readODS isn't succesfull: ERROR: dependency ‘xml2’ is not available for package ‘readODS’
* removing ‘/home/huub/R/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu-library/4.0/readODS’

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/RtmpYYyZxs/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In install.packages("readODS") :
  installation of package ‘xml2’ had non-zero exit status
2: In install.packages("readODS") :
  installation of package ‘readODS’ had non-zero exit status